# Unable to serve picture using NGINX

Tags: nginx

So im trying to serve real time digital clock using nginx server on Ubuntu 18.04. I managed to edit HTML file but the output is not showing it correctly. See picture below.

[click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSCLv.png)

here is my config file in /etct/nginx/site-availabe/default. I have searched the web, from my point i do not understand why nginx does not show it in full scale. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
}

    root /var/www/html;



location /{

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
```

Comment: What does your HTML actually try to display?

Comment: If i understood your question good it should be digital clock in real time. If you like, i can post a HTML file as well.

Comment: what path missing images have

Comment: images are stored inside of an index.html file which is located in /var/www/html/index.html. So there is no partial directories storing jpg pictures etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try rearranging your config a little:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

If your images are embedded in your index.html, this is a basic config and should "just work"

Comment: that said, it would be helpful to see how you are embedding the images.

Comment: Actually there is no curly bracket closing the server block, except that everything has been set in order as you suggested. I have tried to close the server block using curly bracket but now i got an error "Server name directive not allowed here ''

Comment: Okay, manged to fix curly brackets, all good, however still same, pictures are not served as it should be. Reading some NGINX documentation, this format should be good as index html file is being pulled form /var/www/html.  Not sure how to post whole html code since it does not allow to list 2000 characters